# Open Graph API - Github PHP Class

Tags: facebook, api, github, facebook-opengraph

I have downloaded the PHP class from github which is the wrapper for their Open Graph API. I can log in and list freinds and images etc. But what I am really struggling with is allowing for extended permissions to allow posting to a users wall.

I know somewhere I need to add `scope=publish_stream` to allow this option and can only assume it is on the **getLoginUrl** method but I am having next to know joy with it.

Can anyone help me.

Steve

Answer (score 4):

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'publish_stream'));
```